# Submitting an SQL query with a slice parameter

Tags: sql, go, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake query where I'm trying to update a field on all items where another field is in a list which is submitted to the query as a variable:

```
UPDATE my_table SET download_enabled = ? WHERE provider_id = ? AND symbol IN (?)
```

I've tried doing this query using the `gosnowflake.Array` function like this:

```
enable := true
provider := 1
query := "UPDATE my_table SET download_enabled = ? WHERE provider_id = ? AND symbol IN (?)"

if _, err := client.db.ExecContext(ctx, query, enable, provider,
    gosnowflake.Array(assets)); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
```

However, this code fails with the following error:

> 002099 (42601): SQL compilation error: Batch size of 1 for bind variable 1 not the same as previous size of 2.

So then, how can I submit a variable representing a list of values to an SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a potential workaround, which is to submit each item in the list as a separate parameter explicitly:

```
func Delimit(s string, sep string, count uint) string {
    return strings.Repeat(s+sep, int(count)-1) + s
}

func doQuery(enable bool, provider int, assets ...string) error {
    query := fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE my_table SET download_enabled = ? " + 
        "WHERE provider_id = ? AND symbol IN (%s)", Delimit("?", ", ", uint(len(assets))))

    params := []interface{}{enable, provider}
    for _, asset := range assets {
        params = append(params, asset)
    }

    if _, err := client.db.ExecContext(ctx, query, params...); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Needless to say this is a less elegant solution then what I wanted but it does work.